# Save session on Facebook login

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, safari

In my mvc3 facebook application i detect user if login status = connected or let him to login 
by Facebook login popup.After login i save user Facebook id in session:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUserFacebookId"] = FacebookId;
```

The problem is in safari browser. The default settings of safari is to "block cookies from third parties and advertisers". So session is not saved and user can't use my application, because all actions check the session.How to solve this problem?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this by setting the header with a simple [P3P Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P)

> P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND
>   CNT"

Or in PHP:

> header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS
>   OUR IND CNT"');

Or in ASP.NET:

> HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\""IDC DSP COR ADM
>   DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\""")

But I think after Safari 5.5.1 or so this trick doesn't work anymore. I think the only way in Safari 5.5.1 or later is to enable 3rd party cookies/sessions by setting "Block cookies" in Preferences -> Privacy to "Never".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late for this answer.

But, try put in web.config that: 
"forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" **cookieless="UseCookies"**"

Inside the authentication tag. that(**the bold part**) enable the cookies and works for me.

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it works on safari. and avoid the user interact with the preferences.